# C - Makefile compiles after header file changes, but changes dont take effect

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, linker, header-files

I have 3 files in this program, lab4.c, functions.h, functions.c

The lab4.c calls a function multiply(), whose prototype is in functions.h and is defined in functions.c. Multiply then used multiple other functions from functions.c. The only includes I have for this is in lab4.c including functions.h, do I need more? The problem I am having is described below

lab4:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "functions.h"
int main(void) {
...
}
```

functions.h:

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS
#define FUNCTIONS

void divideByPowerOf2(unsigned int* a, int power);
void multiplyByPowerOf2(unsigned int* a, int power);
...
#endif /* FUNCTIONS */
```

functions.c:

```
void divideByPowerOf2(unsigned int* a, int power){
    *a >>= power;
}
void multiplyByPowerOf2(unsigned int* a, int power){
    *a <<= power;
}
...
```

Currently, my makefile looks like this:

Makefile:

```
#Makefile

all: lab4

lab4: lab4.o functions.o functions.h
    gcc -Wall -o lab4 lab4.o functions.o

lab4.0: lab4.c
    gcc -c lab4.c

functions.o: functions.c
    gcc -c functions.c
```

now this will recompile when I change the header file, but the changes dont actually take effect. For example, if I change the header file to

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS
#define FUNCTIONS

void divideByPowerOf2(unsigned int* a, int power);
//void multiplyByPowerOf2(unsigned int* a, int power);
...
#endif /* FUNCTIONS */
```

the program still works just fine. Im assuming I may have messed up linking the files with includes and everything, as that usually confuses me. For example, does functions.c need to refer to anything? and does functions.h need any kind of reference to the .c files? How do I get this to work properly so that if I change the header file, it recompiles and actually uses the new header

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You make the wrong rule depend on `functions.h`.  Think about it. A header file is used when *compiling* a program, not when *linking*.  It is a .c file that `#include`s the .h file, so it is the step that performs the inclusion of `foo.h` (i.e. the preprocessing or compilation step, operating on the `.c` file) that should have `foo.h`  as a dependency. In your case, it's the step that compiles `lab4.c`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there's a typo here:

```
lab4.0: lab4.c
```

should be

```
lab4.o: lab4.c
```

then, your `function.h` should be on the source => object dependency lines, not on the object => executable line, else, if you change the .h file, it just re-links without rebuilding the .o files: it changes nothing.

Moreover, it's good to use `-Wall`, but you have to use it when you compile your files, not when you link the executable, or you'll miss the actual compilation warnings (`-Wall` during the link phase only is pretty useless).

For instance, the `-Wall` flag would show you that commenting a prototype generates an "implicit declaration" warning (which can lead to an improper call/return values of a function). It's even more effective with `-Werror`, which turns warnings into errors, so you cannot ignore warnings.

Here's how your makefile should look like:

```
all: lab4

CFLAGS = -Wall

lab4: lab4.o functions.o
    gcc -o lab4 lab4.o functions.o

lab4.o: lab4.c functions.h
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c lab4.c

functions.o: functions.c functions.h
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c functions.c
```

note that if you only have 2 source files and they're small enough, you could even not use the make file by just running:

```
gcc -Wall -o lab4 lab4.c functions.c
```

in a script. That's not adapted if you have too many / big source files, because it rebuilds everything everytime.

Comment: I tried this, but my files are still working when one of the function is commented out... Could this be because Im linking the functions.o and lab4.o when functions.c contains the function definitions?

Comment: Hmm I deleted lab4 and it wouldnt let me run it, I used ./lab4. I also tried the which lab4 just in case, but it couldnt find it either... Any ideas?

Comment: so when deleting the file, it is not found. When running the last `gcc -Wall -o lab4 lab4.c functions.c` or the current makefile, it just cannot be that your changes aren't reflected in the executable. Try to add some `printf` statements to convince yourself that your changes have an effect.

Comment: oh and if the prototype isn't found, you'll get warnings now with `-Wall` applied to the sources. You'll see that a default prototype is taken from the function absent from the .h file, this default prototype could make your program still work (but I don't advise it): deleting a prototype from a .h file doesn't prevent the program to work or even to compile unless all warnings are turned into errors.

Comment: quoting you: "Could this be because Im linking the functions.o and lab4.o when functions.c contains the function definitions?": answer: yes. but always use prototypes. for instance if you're handling floats you'll have nasty surprises.

Comment: Ahh I think I get it now. Your change to the Makefile adding the -Wall to the -c parts made a warning show up about an implicit function, Im assuming this means that it couldnt find the function prototype (because it was commented out), and only found the definition. For some reason, I was confused thinking that not having a function prototype meant the function wouldnt work (which I guess is good because it means I will always use them!), so I was expecting an error. Seeing the warning helped me understand, thank you for the help!

Comment: Also, am I right in thinking that -Wall is an option that turns on more compiler warnings, which is why it needed to be used with -c and not -o, which is just linking?

Comment: yes, Wall isn't useful in the link phase. Seeing your comments, I see you got all figured out. I was glad to help.